# Android Kernel Zimage unpack

Tags: android, kernel

My question is it possible to unpack a zimage (kernel of android) to get the source, because my phone developer won't publish the code of the kernel, I have write a mail to the Company but no response.
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I edited my answer. And please don't use answer to ask another question just edit your current question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can unpack zImage there are a lot of tool to unpack, but the problem is you can't get the source by this way, it is binary. Android uses GNU/Linux kernel and the phone company must share the kernel source. If you are not looking for vendor specific kernel source you can download kernel source from https://www.kernel.org/

To get your phone's kernel version, in adb shell type:

> uname -a

And your second question;
Recompiling kernel for a phone is time consuming and phone model specific process. It seems you need information about ROM customisation. Google it for "Custom ROM" for your phone model or sites like https://forum.xda-developers.com/